# How can I read a binary file as an array of numbers between 0 and 255 on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hex, histogram

I'm trying `Array.from(fs.readFileSync('test.bin', 'hex)` but the output from `readFile` is a continuous stream so the array is formed with single digits instead of the decimal values for each byte

Comment: *If the encoding option is specified then this function returns a string. Otherwise it returns a buffer.* - did you want a buffer or a string?

Comment: @Bravo I want an array where if a byte is 0x00 the value is 0 and so on up to 0xff being 255. It's for making a histogram

Comment: yes, so, you don't want a string ... it's easy to get an array from a buffer

Comment: Yes, and I do get it without options. But each value as a string instead of a number. Should I convert every one manually?

Comment: no, a Buffer is not at all related to a String `let array = Array.from(fs.readFileSync('test.bin'))` - voila, array is an array of values from 0 to 255 representing the bnary data from tst.bin

Comment: yes, Array.from converts the Buffer of numbers into an array of numbers

Comment: You're right, it was working all along just the way I did it. IDK why I didn't see it. I guess I'll have to go get some sleep. Thanks!

Comment: no it wasn't ... for instance if the file contained `1234` - you would get `"3","1","3","2","3","3","3","4"` ... instead of `[31,32,33,34]` - so it's lucky you asked

Comment: Yes, yes, the way I posted in the question doesn't work, but the first thing I tried before that in my computer was no options.